# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to run the following example unit test case

```
class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Test
    fun addition_is_Correct() {
        assertEquals(4, (2 + 2).toLong())
    }

}
```

but I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/LauncherDiscoveryRequest;)V
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:61)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

even though I have updated all the Junit dependencies build.gradle file like given below

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.1.5'
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5'
testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.3'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0'
```

is there any solution for this?

Comment: I do not see any issue in this, could you share a bit more.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** downgrade your dependencies in `pom.xml` according to versions that originally came with IDEA found in `IDEA_INSTALLATION_HOME/plugins/junit/lib`

---

Longer version:

Let's presume you're using a version of the Intellij IDEA older than 2017.3; then you have these choices that were given as an official answer to another SO question:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000791190-Intellij-does-not-run-Junit5-tests

Pasting it here to to make it more visible:

> IDE has compilation dependency on the old junit 5 launcher jar and it is not compatible with current released version. So you have a choice to update IDE so it will be compatible with the junit version you use or to downgrade the junit version (check what version was bundled in IDEA_INSTALLATION_HOME/plugins/junit/lib). 2017.1 had only experimental support for junit 5 as junit 5 was not released yet at that time. Sorry for the inconvenience.

So, go to your `IDEA_INSTALLATION_HOME/plugins/junit/lib` folder and check the versions in the names of the `jar` files found there.
Should be something like this:

```
user@comp:IDEA_INSTALLATION_HOME/plugins/junit/lib]$ ls
idea-junit.jar                        junit-platform-runner-1.0.0-M4.jar
junit5-rt.jar                         junit-platform-suite-api-1.0.0-M4.jar 
junit-jupiter-api-5.0.0-M4.jar        junit-rt.jar
junit-jupiter-engine-5.0.0-M4.jar     junit-vintage-engine-4.12.0-M4.jar
junit-platform-commons-1.0.0-M4.jar   opentest4j-1.0.0-M2.jar
junit-platform-engine-1.0.0-M4.jar    resources_en.jar
junit-platform-launcher-1.0.0-M4.jar
```

Now use the `junit-` filename's version suffix in your module's `pom.xml` `properties` setup:

```
<project>
...
    <properties>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M4</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M4</junit.platform.version>
        <junit.vintage.version>4.12.0-M4</junit.vintage.version>
        ...
    </properties>
...
</project>
```

I can confirm that after changing to older versions, I could run Test classes that were using `org.junit.jupiter` package. Before this I was constantly getting the `NoSuchMethodError` when trying to run the Tests.

Comment: Well, I use eclipse, and I have encountered the problem.

Comment: @ÁrpádMagosányi I believe it should be a similar process with Eclipse if you're using Maven. I'd say go to the Eclipse's equivalent of the dependencies folder and get the versions there. I don't have Eclipse so i don't know the exact procedure, but compare my, Christian Nuss's and hd84335's solution, maybe that will help you.

Comment: As I remember the solution for me was the one @hd84335 has given.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade `junit-platform-launcher` version from `1.0.0` to `1.4.x` may still be needed in order to be able to run your `junit5` tests:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've experienced a very similar problem in *eclipse*, and found the solution [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545849)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing something similar in VSCode, and thought I'd share my result.

I was using a mis-mash of testing dependencies in my `pom.xml`, which I saw by doing `mvn dependency:tree`. Removing Specific `junit-jupiter` dependencies and simply using `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter` made everything work again (both the Test Execution in VSCode, and `mvn test` on the command line).

Ultimately the only Jupiter dependencies I have in my `pom.xml` now is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Source: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1773

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me actually wound up being the gradle configuration. The project in IntelliJ was using a gradle wrapper. Modifying the configuration to use the local installation (so I know it's correct) instead of the wrapper fixed the jUnit issue.

Just a note on how I found this:

I always double check if projects build via command line. If so, I know it's an IDE issue. Then it's just a matter of making sure the IDE is using the same tools.