# Junit 5 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute

Tags: junit5

Below is my POM file. My question is about resolving NoSuchMethodError.

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit/junit5-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-launcher -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>5.5.2</version>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
```

I referred the below link for my POM:
[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323335/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-junit-platform-launcher-launcher-execute) 
and also referred other stackoverflow suggestions - baeldung but didn't work. I am not using Spring, simple java program.

Thanks